# CSS HTML align div

Tags: html, css

I have div tag inside body

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    background:#787777;
    font-family:"Droid Sans",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:0.81em;
    }

#header{
    height:100px;
    background:#000000;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    }
```

and here is result as you see there is spaces left, top and right. How i can remove this spaces?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body{
    background:#787777;
    font-family:"Droid Sans",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:0.81em;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just adding margin:0 to the body selector should do it

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943560/html-alignment-issue-in-one-machine-only-both-ie8 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the margin and padding around the `<body>` element. Browsers will add one or the other by default, so you need to explicitly set them to 0:

```
body {
    background:#787777;
    font-family:"Droid Sans",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:0.81em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Different browsers have different default styles, so setting both padding *and* margin to 0 ensures you don't get a gap.